# How to hide image on pressing textinput in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my current code..

I am totally new to react native..please help.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput,StatusBar, SafeAreaView,Image,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
  return (      
    <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput 
      
      placeholder="Search"
      style={styles.searchbox}                        
    ></TextInput>        
    <View style={styles.makecentral} > 
    <Image                  
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')}        
      />
    </View>
  </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',    
  },
  searchbox:{
    backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
    marginTop : StatusBar.currentHeight+5,
    height : 50,
    marginLeft:10,
    marginRight : 10,
    borderRadius : 20,
    textAlignVertical:'center',
    textAlign : 'center',
    alignItems:'center',        
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    position : 'absolute',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    opacity: 0.5,
    marginTop: -40,    
  },
  makecentral: {
    alignItems:'center',
    marginRight:80,    
  }  
});
```

I want to hide the search image by pressing text input.

I have an image in search box and I want to hide that image when the user touch text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {  useState } from 'react'; //import useState
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput,StatusBar, SafeAreaView,Image,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); //add this line
  return (      
    <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
      placeholder="Search"
      style={styles.searchbox}                        
    ></TextInput>        
    <View style={styles.makecentral} >   
    {search.length < 1 ? <Image               
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')}        
      /> : ( 
          null  //add clear text image and clear search text
      )}
    
    </View>
  </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',    
  },
  searchbox:{
    backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
    marginTop : StatusBar.currentHeight+5,
    height : 50,
    marginLeft:10,
    marginRight : 10,
    borderRadius : 20,
    textAlignVertical:'center',
    textAlign : 'center',
    alignItems:'center',        
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    position : 'absolute',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    opacity: 0.5,
    marginTop: -40,    
  },
  makecentral: {
    alignItems:'center',
    marginRight:80,    
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a combination of a show/hide state for the image coupled with an `onFocus` and `onBlur` (*if you want to again display image when focus is lost*) callback set to conditionally render the image.

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);

  return (      
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="Search"
          style={styles.searchbox}
          onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
          onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
        />        
        <View style={styles.makecentral}> 
          {!inputFocused && <Image                  
            style={styles.tinyLogo}
            source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')}        
          />}
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```